# Convert 8bit sRGB to 4bit grayscale with ImageMagick

Tags: png, imagemagick, file-conversion

I want to print an 8bit sRGB PNG image on an Epson TM-T88v receipt printer. The printer needs a 4bit grayscale PNG file to print it correctly.

As I'm using PHP with ImageMagick, I'm not sure which commands are needed to convert the image.

If I use ImageMagick's "identify" and "convert" on the linux console on the 8bit input image I get following output:

> ```
> test.png PNG 128x128 128x128+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.78KB 0.000u 0:00.000
> ```

I've tried...

```
convert test.png -depth 4 -colorspace gray test-4bit.png
```

which gives me still an 8bit image instead of 4bit

> ```
> test-4bit.png PNG 128x128 128x128+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.58KB 0.000u 0:00.000
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried `magick source.png -colorspace gray -depth 4 destination.png` using ImageMagick 7.0.7-28 Q16 x64 2018-03-25 and it seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea why but `identify` seems to always assume sRGB. Your image should actually be grayscale. If you use the [`-verbose`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#verbose) option it will report the correct color space.

For the bit-depth you need to explicitly set the color-type and bit-depth for the PNG encoder by using [`-define`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define).

This should work:

```
convert test.png -depth 4 -colorspace gray -define png:color-type=0 -define png:bit-depth=4 test-4bit-gray.png
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you! One question: identify -verbose tells me "color: 12".... shouldn't a 4bit per pixel image have 4² = 16 colors?

Comment: @ninsky no idea sorry.. my limited tests now give me colors: 16

Comment: Just converted another image: "colors" means "used colors" in context of the identified image (not "maximum color space")... so it's ok