# Prevent white border effect when converting an image to grayscale with ImageMagick

Tags: color-conversion, imagemagick, file-conversion

For printing images on a Epson TM-T88v receipt printer, [I had to convert](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76004/convert-8bit-srgb-to-4bit-grayscale-with-imagemagick) a PNG file to a 4-bit grayscale PNG by using ImageMagick.

Using the following command I'm getting pretty good results except of a white border around certain parts of the converted image:

```
convert test.png -depth 4 -colorspace gray -define png:color-type=0 -define png:bit-depth=4 test-4bit-gray.png
```

Original input image:

[image: Original image]

Converted image:

[image: Converted image with ImageMagick]

If I use Epson's native JS library to convert PNG images to 4-bit grayscale I get following result which looks way smoother:

[image: Converted image with native Epson library]

Which ImageMagick options could help me to avoid the white border around the heart eyes of the Emoji or make it to look smoother at all?

Comment: Looks like an anti-aliasing issue to me.  I never use imagemagic, so I'm not sure if/how to adjust those settings, but if you do, start there.  On second thought, you could increase your bit depth.  That might help. increase it to 8-24, if you can.

Comment: @Manly, thanks. Need to have exactly a 4-bit depth. The Epson example has also 4-bit. Will look for an anti-aliasing option...

Comment: What you want is some dithering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_photography_and_image_processing). There is some information on dithering techniques using ImageMagick here:

- [ImageMagick v6 Examples — Color Quantization and Dithering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/)

Using [`-ordered-dither`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#ordered-dither) for the dither and removing the alpha gets you pretty close:

[image: Dithered 4Bit Grayscale Conversion with ImageMagick]

Converted with:

```
convert test.png -depth 4 -colorspace gray -alpha remove -ordered-dither o2x2,16 -define png:color-type=0 -define png:bit-depth=4 test-4bit-gray.png
```